# blogdown rmarkdown::render_site can't find config.toml when running from different project than site

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, hugo, blogdown

### Website build

#### within WebSite Project

I have a website generated using blogdown and a Hugo template.

The site can be build using the *build tab >> Build Website* button in R-studio or just using the following coding, executed from source or console within the same R-studio Project

```
rmarkdown::render_site(
 input = "c:\\WebSite", 
 encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

> Building sites â€¦ 
>                      | EN
>   +------------------+----+
>     Pages            | 66
>     Paginator pages  |  0
>     Non-page files   |  0
>     Static files     | 21
>     Processed images |  0
>     Aliases          | 19
>     Sitemaps         |  1
>     Cleaned          |  0

Total in 637 ms

Output created: C:\Public/index.html

---

#### outside WebSite Project

As I have multiple websites with different layouts, I generate the posts (*.md files) from one master Project. This works fine

However I can't build the website from this project using the same coding although the path is absolute.

```
rmarkdown::render_site(
 input = "c:\\WebSite", 
 encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

> Error in find_config() : 
>     Cannot find the configuration file config.toml | config.yaml of the website